# OpenGL texture lookup error

Tags: opengl, textures

I get an error while executing the following fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

in vec4 pos;           // <-- input (x,y,z) position normalized to [0, 1] 
in vec4 screenPos;     // <-- input screen position normalized to [-1, 1] 
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler3D volumeTex;    // <-- a volume
uniform sampler2D backFaceTex;  // <-- the backface of a cube previously saved to texture

void main()
{
    if(gl_FrontFacing) {
        vec4 front = pos;
        vec4 back = texture(backFaceTex, (screenPos.xy/screenPos.w+1.0)/2.0);

        // only one of the following 4 lines is uncommented at a time
        outColor = front;                          // <-- Ok
        outColor = back;                           // <-- Ok
        outColor = texture(volumeTex, front.xyz);  // <-- Ok
        outColor = texture(volumeTex, back.xyz);   // <-- Error
    }
    else {
        discard;
    }
}
```

As you can read from my comments the program runs fine, rendering the images I expect, in the first three cases, but fails in the forth (the only one I need).

Nothing is rendered and I get an error from glGetError() in the main app.

It seems like it is forbidden to use a texel as the coordinate parameter for another texture fetch operation.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: What is the error from `glGetError()` and on which call does it happen? What does the shader compiler log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou derhass,

I found where the problem is:
I was using the same texture unit for both the 3D and 2D samplers, and this is illegal.
Keeping the code as it is, and simply using texture unit 0 for sampler3D and texture unit 1 for sampler2D, for example, solves the problem!

Cheers,
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Using the result of a texture fetch as coordinates for another texture fetch is called a dependent texture fetch and is perfectly valid (although it might have some negative impact on the performance compared to an independent fecth).

The problem in your code is most likely the

```
vec4 back = texture(backFaceTex, (screenPos.xy/screenPos.w+1.0)/2.0);
```

line, where you basically have an (vec2(...) + 1.0) operation which is just not allowed and should result in a compilation error. That would also explain the fact that nothing is drawn and you get an error when trying to draw (without a valid program).